# Как передать картинку с хостинга Digital Ocean на сайт? Golang

Tags: golang, hosting, digitalocean

Я задеплоил двоичный файл на хостинг DO. Это проект на golang, в админке которого я могу создавать карточки. Карточка содержит заголовок и картинку. От картинки сохраняется в БД только путь до неё. Однако на сервере двоичный файл не может содержать заранее эти картинки, они добавляются по мере надобности. Поэтому я заметил, что при сохранении карточки, картинка сохраняется в определенной директории рядом с этим двоичным файлом:

```
x@x-production:~$ ls
assets  migrations  web
```

web - файл проекта;
assets - директория с картинками карточки;
Например, в assets путь до картинки обложки каталога выглядит так:

```
x@x-production:~/assets/static/img/catalog/2$ ls
1708864387803037959.webp
```

Эта картинка действительно существует.
Вопрос в том, как передать путь до неё на сайт? Потому что

```
x.ru/static/img/catalog/*/*.webp
```

или

```
x.ru/static/img/catalog/*/*.webp
```

не работает. Может это потому, что двоичный файл ищет эти пути непосредственно в своей статике?
Неужели придется подключать Spaces Object Storage?
Для прокси я использую Caddy:

```
x.ru {
    reverse_proxy localhost:4000
}
```

я не особо разбираюсь еще в этом, но вот так тоже не работает (здесь я хотел хотя бы явно докопаться до картинки):

```
x.ru {
    reverse_proxy localhost:4000

    root * /assets
    file_server

    route /static/img/catalog/2/1708864387803037959.webp {
        root * /assets/static/img/catalog/2
        file_server
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Почитав документацию я понял, что есть функция "route" которая явно позиционирует выполнение запросов. До этого мой прокси перехватывал все запросы

```
x.ru {
    route {
        encode gzip

        file_server /static/* browse {
            root /home/stm/assets
        }

        reverse_proxy * localhost:4000
    }
}
```